# ¿Existen alternativas al diccionario inverso Dirae?

Tags: recursos, diccionarios

La web de nuestra amadísima [Dirae](https://dirae.es) muestra este mensaje:

> Lo sentimos, Dirae.es cesa en su actividad por amenazas legales de la Real Academia Española por uso de su marca registrada "RAE".
>
> Gracias por haberlo usado todos estos años.

Es honda la tristeza al leer esta noticia y me plantea la duda: ¿existe algún otro diccionario equivalente? ¿Existe alguna copia del sitio?

Comment: Existe una alternativa de pago (Enclave RAE), como [nos explicó Charlie](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4344/24236). Quizá por eso ha habido esas "amenazas legales"... una pena.

Comment: Y gracias desde aquí al usuario que lo creó, que es usuario de este sitio también.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues parece que ya tenemos un recurso casi igual :)

#### [Iedra](https://iedra.es) ([www.iedra.es](https://iedra.es))

> Iedra es un buscador y explorador de palabras. Se puede entender como lo opuesto a un diccionario ordinario. En estos, se parte de una palabra para hallar su definición. En Iedra, se parte de una definición y se hallan las palabras que la satisfacen.

Básicamente, parece ser DIRAE con un nombre diferente para no contener *RAE* en él. Me parece un nombre sumamente interesante, pues me evoca tanto a la [*hiedra*](https://dle.rae.es/hiedra), planta trepadora que se adapta, como a la [hidra mitológica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidra_de_Lerna) con múltiples cabezas.

Bien jugado, qué alegría volver a tener este recurso a mano.

Answer (score 6):

Se puede usar las herramientas de Google de una manera similar. Por ejemplo, para recoger entradas de orígen hindi:

> [site:dle.rae.es "Del hindi"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adle.rae.es+%22Del+hindi%22)

o para recoger entradas que contienen la frase "ave [...] del tamaño":

> [site:dle.rae.es "ave * del tamaño"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adle.rae.es+%22ave+*+del+tama%C3%B1o%22)